# What are some ways to implement a hierarchical taxonomy page structure?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

I'm currently trying to decide how to architect a client's site, and they need to have the need to have a hierarchical page structure. This must be able to go at least 3 levels in depth and have the option of exposing various filters.

I would assume that using a view that accepts multiple arguments and using taxonomies would be the way to go about developing this, but I wanted to ask this community if there were any contrib module alternatives I might look into as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drupal taxonomy was born for these needs.

And *Views* is perfect if you need simple filters.

If it's a high volume of pages and search functionality is going to be important, you can integrate it with [Apache Solr](http://drupal.org/project/apachesolr) and use **Facets** to filter. What better example than [drupal.org](http://drupal.org/search/apachesolr_search/example)